# Elasticsearch - NEST - Elasticsearch.NET - Filtering after search

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, filter, nest

I'm asking myself, if it is possible to filter the results of an `SearchResponse` with an own method from my C# Code. So that I could paste in an Action which is filtering the resultset?

```
var desc = new SearchDescriptor<T>();
desc.Query(q => SomeSearch);
var searchResponse = Client.Search<T>(desc);
var filteredData = searchResponse.Documents.Any() ? Filter(searchResponse.Documents, options.SenderXid) : searchResponse.Documents;
```

Comment: filter the results on Elasticsearch, or filter in the application on the response returned from Elasticsearch?

Comment: @RussCam If possible i want to filter the `SearchResponse`, so that i have a `SearchResponse`-Object with Filtered Values after. Currently im Filtering the List of Objects which is returned in the response. So i can only give back the List of objects, but not the whole `SearchResponse`. I would like to give Elasticsearch an method, which is filtering the `SearchResponse`after Searching.

Comment: so you want the filtering to happen on the Elasticsearch side? Can you give an example of what you're doing now?

Comment: @RussCam Im adding a code sample what im doing now. Yes you are right, if possible i want to the filtering on server side, but the aggregator functions arent matching my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you could do this:

```
var searchResponse = Client.Search<T>(desc);
var postFilteredData = searchResponse.Hits.Where(x=>x.Date > something);
```

Is that what you're looking to do?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But thats not what I am looking for. This would just give me a filtered list, like im doing somehow. I want to give a filtered SearchResponse Class back.